# Packaging a Python Project to an Executable

Tags: python

I have a project with the below structure:

```
projectname/projectname/__main__.py
```

I execute the program using `python -m projectname`.

If I want to install it locally in my system so that I can just call `projectname`, How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/828737/run-python-scripts-without-explicitly-invoking-python

Comment: The answers linked above will only work if your script is in your pwd though...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make a file `setup.py` in the top-level `projectname` that installs the package and adds some command (e.g. `yeet`) to your path. That command will call some function inside `projectname/__main__.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
  name='mypackagename',
  version='0.0.1',
  packages=['mypackagename'],
  install_requires=[
    'tensorflow>=2.0.0', # put your modules from requirements.txt here
  ],
  entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
      'yeet=projectname:function_to_run',
    ],
  },
)
```